# Can't override paypal profile based shipping

Tags: php, html, paypal

I have included this code in my add to cart buttons.

```html
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0.00">
```

In the shipping calculations I have this box "Use the shipping fee in the transaction instead of my calculator's settings:" checked as yes, and the shipping costs are based on quantity. None of this has worked the shipping is still not change to the override cost.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
```